# Test a negative directional hypothesis

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have a conceptual question regarding the testing of a directional hypothesis in regressions.

Usually, we test a higher-higher relationship: The higher X -> the higher Y.

What if my hypothesis is this: the lower X -> the higher value Y.

Example: The lower the number of Books someone owns, the higher number of hours spent on Netflix every week.

If I have data on the number of books and weekly Netflix hours, can I simply test that with a standard regression analysis or do I need to use a specific test?

Wouldn’t statistical significance of X normally indicate that higher X (number of books) -> higher Y (Netflix hours)?

Comment: Yes, you can use regular regression (if the data otherwise allows it). When you have a significant relationship in the form of lower X -> higher Y, you will find a regression coefficient for X that is negative and statistically significant. (when in the case of higher X -> higher Y the coefficient for X will be positive and statistically significant).

Comment: Welcome to CV.SE. Another way of putting what Sointu said - if we constraint ourselves to only testing "higher-higher relationships", what can you conclude if you test the relationship between -X (negative X) and Y?

Comment: Thanks you two! Stats training has been a while, and now the basics are a bit rusty...